# Samsung Galaxy S7 Edge (SK Telecom unlocked) no calls or SMS using Verizon SIM

Tags: verizon, samsung-galaxy-s-7-edge

I have purchased Samsung Galaxy S7 Edge unlocked from ebay. It's SK Telecom unlocked phone. It accepts SIM card from Verizon and registers on network successfully but I'm unable to make and receive calls. SMS doesn't work as well. What are my options? Should I try rooting the device and install a Nougat ROM provided by Samsung or there may be something wrong with some settings?

Comment: What is the exact model number of the phone? Remember that Verizon uses CDMA and LTE in their network, most phones from outside the US do not support Verizon's bands (frequencies) in the CDMA network. Most phones on Verizon still use CDMA for SMS messaging.

Comment: As a supplement to the above, Korean variants (Exynos 8890) don't have CDMA capabilities indeed.

Comment: Have you tried the very same SIM card in another phone? If it has the same issues there, it might be the SIM or some broken settings at the provider's end.

Comment: Thanks guys for your comments. It was indeed unlocked GSM phone. When I used a GSM SIM, it worked. Still using it.